# Angular 2 how to bind a div element?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 <div *ngFor="let city of 
   israelCitieService.data|mychoosedcities:wordSerched;let i=index"
 </div>
```

I want to know the length of the array returned from the pipe.
 and the index (i) is unknown outside of the div element.
 how sould I bind it to with my component?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this: `let l = israelCitieService.data|mychoosedcities:wordSerched.length;`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let cityofisraelCitieService.data|mychoosedcities:wordSerche as array;let i=index">
  <div (click)="passIndexValue(array)"></div> 
<div>
<div>{{lenght}}</div>
```

in your component :

```
passIndexValue(array){
   this.lenght = array.length ;
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work. in addition I dont need the information of the index in event click. the divs are shown like a list and I want to know their length.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to follow the Angular team's advice of not using pipes for data manipulation: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Therefore moving your filter logic to your controller, storing the data on a variable would also allow you to update the length correctly! If you then take care of change detection and put an index on your loop, this should give you the best performance you can achieve!